# Analysis with $\chi^2$ test

Tags: statistics

I have a set of results on the number of decays in $7.5$s intervals.

$$
\begin{array}
  \hline \hline
  \mathbf{Decays} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
  \mathbf{Frequency} & 20 & 203 & 401 & 511\\
  \hline
\end{array} $$
I'm meant to use $\chi^2$ to test if this data is consistent with a Poisson distribution, and I'm having two problems.

So I need to calculate the mean using $\frac{203+802 + 1533}{20+203+401+511}=2.2$, because the expected value in the proposed model is the mean. Also the square of the standard deviation is the mean. So:
$$\chi^2 = \Sigma_i \frac{(x_i -<x>)^2}{\sigma_i^2} = \Sigma_i \frac{(x_i -\bar{x})^2}{\bar{x}}$$
$$=\frac{20\times(0-2.2^2)}{2.2}+\frac{203\times (1-2.2)^2}{2.2}+...$$
This is one of the problems: the $\chi^2$ value is huge. It's 332. I can't look that up in any table I've ever seen, so what am I doing wrong? I also don't know how many degrees of freedom there are - normally I'd say it's the number of measurements, but that's also huge and not in any table. If someone could point out where I'm going wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is right in finding the mean and that would be your proposed mean of the Poisson distribution.  Now with that as $\lambda$ compute theoretical frequency using the Poisson Distribution which is $n\times$theoretical probability, where it is $P(X=k) = \dfrac{e^{-\lambda}.\lambda^k}{k!}$

Now compute $\chi^2_{statistic} = \sum_{k} \dfrac{(f_0-f_t)^2}{f_t}$ with 2 degress of freedom $(k-p-1) (4-1-1)$ where k=4 is the number of classes and p=1 is one parameter $\lambda$ being estimated.

For this degress of freedom look up critical value for some level of significance and reject $H_0:$ that the data follows Poisson distribution if the statistic is greater than critical. Else do not reject $H_0$